# cd into another directory to execute a script

Tags: python

I need to cd into a particular directory to run a jar package. This is what I'm currently trying to do, albeit unsucessfully:

```
subprocess.call(['cd','sales'])
subprocess.call(shlex.split("""java Autoingestion %s %s %s Sales Daily Details %s"""%                                                                         
            (self.username, self.password, self.vendor_number, self.date)))
```

How would I correctly cd into the sales folder and execute this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
subprocess.call(["java","Autoingestion",self.username, self.password, self.vendor_number, "Sales","Daily","Details",self.date, cwd="sales")
```

Notice that you should not do shlex.split as it is insecure

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`os.chdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os-file-dir) before creating the Java subprocess.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`os.chdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir) before your second `Popen` call (and get rid of the first `Popen` call).

Answer (score 0):

Use [os.chdir()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm) to change the current directory to a specified one.

I would suggest you to use [subprocess.Popen()](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) rather than subprocess.call(). If you wish to set the environment yourself before running the java code, like setting JAVA_PATH, etc, it is easy by setting the env argument of Popen.

```
from subprocess import Popen
from os import chdir
from os.path import exists

sales_dir = "/home/ubuntu/sales"

# Sanity check for the directory
if exists(sales_dir):
    chdir(sales_dir)

new_proces = Popen("java Autoingestion %s %s %s Sales Daily Details %s" % 
             (self.username, self.password, self.vendor_number, self.date))
```